# Require.js and Zend Framework

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, requirejs

What is best way for including Require.js in Zend Framework? My current way of calling js files in zend framework are as follow :

```
<?php echo $this->jQuery()->setLocalPath($this->path('js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'))
    ->enable()
    ->setUiLocalPath($this->path('js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js'))
    ->uiEnable()
    ->addStylesheet($this->path('css/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css'));

    echo $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->path('js/jquery.tipTip.js'))

        ->appendFile($this->path('js/customScripts/facebook.js'))
        ->appendFile($this->path('js/facebook/jquery.facebook.multifriend.select.js'))
        ->appendFile($this->path('js/customScripts/logindialog.js'))
        ->appendFile($this->path('js/customScripts/globalFunctions.js'))
        ->appendFile($this->path('js/kendo.web.min.js'))
        ->appendFile($this->path('js/customScripts/fancyAlert.js'))
        ->appendFile($this->path('js/inc/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'))
        ->appendFile($this->path('js/pagination-jq.js'))


        ->appendFile($this->path('js/jquery.tools.min.js'))
        ->appendFile($this->path('js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js'))
        ->appendFile($this->path('js/jq-history/scripts/jquery.history.min.js'));

    ?>
```

Comment: you look at includes like this and it's no wonder most of the pages I visit are slower then pond water, and this one isn't that bad. :(

Answer (score 2):

with require.js you'll only want to add one script file to your head (or just before closing `</body>`).

Then, it's in the require.js config file and modules that you'll actually define the dependencie of each modules.

In your case, I'll just add the script file manually:

```
<script src="require.js" data-main="path/to/mainScriptFile"></script>
```

Or else, in Zend you could do it as so:

```
$this->headScript()
    ->setAllowArbitraryAttributes(true)
    ->appendFile($this->path('js/require.js'), "text/javascript", array('data-main' => 'path/to/mainScriptFile');
```

But at this point, just enter manually a script tag, it's way less overhead.

Hope this help !

Answer (score 0):

In your html file you could add the line in between `<head></head>` tags.This is best approach

```
<script src="/path/to/require.js"></script>
```

or You could go with jquery

```
var jsScript = $("<script src='/path/to/require.js'></script>");
$('body').append(txt2);
```

this will append the js at the bottom of the body